# Shake 'em on down

Tags: slang, lyrics

In 1937 Bukka White recorded a blues song under the title of "Shake 'em on down". Part of the lyrics are cited on Wikipedia:

> Get your nightcap mama, and your gown
>   Baby 'fore day we gonna shake 'em on down
>   Hey done stopped hollerin', oh, must I shake 'em on down
>   I done stopped hollerin' now, must I shake 'em on down

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shake_%27Em_On_Down

**What does the phrase "shake 'em on down" mean, and how does it mean that?**

I understand from the context that the meaning is sexual, but I cannot deduce that from the phrase itself, so what semantic, connotational or other aspects make the phrase mean what it means?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about interpreting song lyrics

Comment: _shake_ is obviously referring to all the movement that takes place in rigorous sex.

Comment: I still don't understand why we have a 'lyrics' tag if questions about song lyrics are off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tom Dalzell, *The Slang of Sin* (1998) lists numerous forms of the word *shake* that apply to such varied pursuits as sex, drugs, gambling, street crime, and dancing. One of the most interesting is this one, for *shake joint*:

> **shake joint** A "dancing studio" of the 1930s where customers and "dancers" would engage in intimate caresses—**shaking**—while fully clothed.

Harold Wentworth & Stuart Flexner, *Dictionary of American Slang* (1960) has this entry for *shake* as an intransitive verb:

> **shake** ... *v.i.* **1** To wiggle one's hips in a lascivious manner. See **bump, grind, shimmy.** **2** To dance. *Facetious.* *v.t.* To shake down someone [in the sense either of "search a person for contraband" or "extort money by blackmail."

I'm not sure what to make of the label "*Facetious*" attached to the definition "To dance," but if one meaning of *shake* is to wiggle one's hips, then whether in the context of dancing or of sexual activity, the *'em* in the ambiguous phrase "shake 'em down" probably refers to "hips."

As for the whole phrase "shake 'em down," I think that it has been used in songs where, at the very least, the meaning as between sex and dancing is not obviously "sex." Case in point: "[Do You Love Me](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7f9O2omYaIo)" by the Contours (1962):

> You broke my heart, 'cause I couldn't dance. You didn't even want me around. And now I'm back, to let you know I can really **shake 'em down**! Do you love me? (I can really move.) Do you love me? (I'm in the groove) Now do you love me? (Do you love me?) Now that I can dance (dance)—watch me now! (Hey, work, work!) Oh work it out baby! (Work, work!) Well you drivin' me crazy! (Work, work!) Just a little bit of soul now. (Work!) I can mash potato. (I can mash potato.) I can do the twist. (I can do the twist.) Now tell me baby. (Tell me baby.) Do you like it like this? (Do you like it like this?) ... watch me now! (Work, work!) Oh **shake it up**, shake it! (Work, work!) Ah shake it, **shake it down**! (Work, work!) Oh little bit of soul now. (Work!) ...

Now, I don't deny that *dance* itself can be used euphemistically to mean "perform sexually"; but it's also true that it can be used to mean "dance," recalling the comment [often attributed to Freud](http://quoteinvestigator.com/2011/08/12/just-a-cigar/) that "a cigar is sometimes just a cigar."

Whether "shake 'em down" was originally used specifically to refer to sexual gyrations or whether it was first associated with dancing (or for that matter walking) provocatively, I can't say. But it clearly has been used in both senses on many occasions since.

---

A Google Books search for "shake 'em down" finds examples from considerably before 1937 (or 1929), where the sense of the phrase is to shake (usually desirable) things out of a tree and down to people waiting below. For example, from Emily Morgan, "[Under the Dream Tree](https://books.google.com/books?id=OmIDAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA436&dq=%22shake+%27em+down%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=RFw0Vc-qFMjeoAS17oCADw&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22shake%20%27em%20down%22&f=false)," in *Mind* (April 1904):

> Then the God o' Dreams answered ole black Satan:
>
> "There won't be none o' them bad if you let 'em alone. The children is going to be good forever and ever; and the Angels is a goin' to **shake 'em down** all kinds o' nice things from the dream-tree when they're asleep."

From P.E.S., "[Bill's and My Coon Hunt](https://books.google.com/books?id=Uy7OAAAAMAAJ&pg=RA1-PA89&dq=%22shake+%27em+down%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=RFw0Vc-qFMjeoAS17oCADw&ved=0CDMQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22shake%20%27em%20down%22&f=false)," in *Hunter—Trader—Trapper* (May 1912):

> Wal, awl thet noise woke up ole Mr. Coon an he begun 2 take hisself apart an 1 uv im went clene tu the top uv the tree.
>
> "Gee! Luk a that! Thares too uv em! Yu better git along up an **shake em down** if you are goin' tu."

This sense of "shake 'em down" may at first blush seem not very closely related to anything sexual. But consider the extended double entendre of Blind Lemon Jefferson's "[Peach Orchard Mama](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8KgZ44jQW0w)" (1929):

> Peach orchard mama, you swore nobody’d pick your fruit but me./Peach orchard mama, you swore that no one picked your fruit but me./I found three kid men **shaking down** your peaches free.

So it's not impossible that "shake 'em on down" could be an allusion to the well-known blues metaphor "shake your peaches on down." The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitting_on_Top_of_the_World) on the Vinson/Chatmon blues song "[Sitting on Top of the World](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N_Kr_OFoqbI)," includes an interesting discussion of what it calls "the 'peaches' verse" (which isn't included in the 1930 Mississippi Sheiks and early Sam Chatmon versions):

> The ‘peaches’ verse has a long history in popular music. It appears as the chorus of an unpublished song composed by Irving Berlin in May 1914: “If you don't want my peaches / You'd better stop shaking my tree”. The song "Mamma's Got the Blues", written by Clarence Williams and S. Martin and recorded by Bessie Smith in 1923, has the line: "If you don't like my peaches then let my orchard be". In her version of "St. Louis Blues", Ella Fitzgerald sang, "If you don't like my peaches, why do you shake my tree? / Stay out of my orchard, and let my peach tree be". In 1929 Blind Lemon Jefferson recorded "Peach Orchard Mama" ...

I first heard it in the Holy Modal Rounders version of "[Hesitation Blues](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FyH5kbe1_oU)" (1964):

> There's a T for Texas, also Tennessee./If you don't like my peaches, stop shakin' my tree./Tell me how long a-do I have to wait?/Or can I get you now, or must I hesitate?

—a version that clearly owes a great debt to Charlie Poole's 1930 version of the same song, under the title "[If the River Was Whiskey](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rL4J-XIAKvw)."

Comment: Wow, now that's an answer! Wonderful. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1):

If a phrase is unique to a specific song, then explaining it requires interpretation, because there is no convention from outside that singular usage to explain its meaning. If, on the other hand, a phrase is common to the everyday language of the community of the singer, then understanding that phrase does not require interpretation but familiarity with the language spoken in the singer's community.

Quite obviously the opinion of some users of this site that my question asks for an interpretatipn of the song's lyrics stems from their ignorance of black southern slang of the early twentieth century.

---

Since y'all seem preoccupied with the site rules, I'm gonna answer my own question:

"Shake", as Stephen Calt explains in his *Barrelhouse Words: A Blues Dialect Dictionary* (p. 210), is "a blues euphemism for engaging in sex". He counts only one song where "shake" does *not* mean sex.

"Shake ... on down" (p. 211) is "[a]n obscure sexual idiom that likely means to initiate sexual activity". It appears as "shook her kid man down" in Willie Baker's "No no blues" from 1929.

Answer (score 0):

Please always post a [**lyrics link**](http://www.lyricsmode.com/lyrics/b/bukka_white/shake_em_on_down.html).

Generally such stuff is found at Yahoo with a search like this:

**"shake 'em on down" meaning**

Sooner or later, you're going to find a relevant link, such as [this one](http://ask.metafilter.com/208788/Must-I-Holler-Must-I-Shake-Em-On-Down). Hope no one is going to complain I didn't bring the contents over :-)